# $a_{n}=\sup \left\{x_{k}: k \geq n\right\} .$ If $a_{i}<a_{j}$ for some $i>j \in \mathbb{N},$ then $a_{j} \in\left\{x_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ be a sequence, and define $a_{n}=\sup \left\{x_{k}: k \geq n\right\} .$ If $a_{i}<a_{j}$ for some $i>j \in \mathbb{N},$ then $a_{j} \in\left\{x_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

I am just a few chapters into an intro to real analysis course. This is a prove or disprove.

Honestly, I am pretty lost on this one even though it seems like it should be simple. $a_n$ is the supremum of a tail of the sequence. However, I know a supremum doesn't have to be in the sequence itself. So I believe this is asking "under these conditions, is $a_j$ actually in the original set that you are taking the supremum of?" But... I have no idea. I feel like we are given very little information. If it's false, I am not sure how I would disprove it. And if it is true, I don't know how to prove it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Generally, the easiest way to disprove something like this is to find a counter-example. Have you tried that and, if so, what did you try and where did you have difficulties?

Comment: My biggest issue is that I don't even know what a counter-example would look like here because we have such little information. $a_i < a_j$ but $i>j$ so we know our sequence is monotone decreasing. I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Well, I guess our sequence isn't monotone decreasing. The sequence of supremums is monotone decreasing? I just can't even figure out how to pick this problem apart.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I took a closer look at this to realize you shouldn't be able to find any counter-examples because, unless I made a mistake, there aren't any. I've provided an answer which I hope you find useful in explaining why the provided statement is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ sequence defined in terms of the $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ sequence as

$$a_{n}=\sup \left\{x_{k}: k \geq n\right\} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You're asked to either prove or disprove that if $a_{i}<a_{j}$ for some $i>j \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a_{j} \in\left\{x_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.

Note that you have for any $m \gt n$ that

$$a_{n} = \max(\sup \left\{x_{k}: n \le k \lt m\right\}, \sup \left\{x_{k}: k \geq m \right\}) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This is relatively easy to verify since, if any value among those with indices $n \le k \lt m$ is larger than or equal to all of the ones for $k \ge m$, then the supremum (actually, maximum since it's a non-empty, finite set) of this first subset would be at least as large as that of the other values and, thus, would be equal to the supremum overall. Otherwise, the supremum of the first finite set would be less than the supremum of the second set, and thus the supremum of the entire set would be equal to the supremum of the second set, i.e., for all $k \ge m$.

Using this, for $a_i \lt a_j$ for some $i \gt j$  means

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_{j} & = \max(\sup \left\{x_{k}: j \le k \lt i\right\}, \sup \left\{x_{k}: k \geq i \right\}) \\
& = \max(\sup \left\{x_{k}: j \le k \lt i\right\}, a_{i}) \\
& = \sup \left\{x_{k}: j \le k \lt i\right\}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since the number of elements in the non-empty set $\left\{x_{k}: j \le k \lt i\right\}$ is finite, in particular it has $i - j$ elements, the supremum is the maximum of the elements and, thus, is equal to one of the elements of the set. In other words, you then have that

$$a_{j} \in\left\{x_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This shows the requested statement is always true.

Comment: I think this makes sense overall. There are still a few bits I need to think through and write out on my own though. Thanks!

Comment: @Hmm You're welcome. I've found that being able to deal with supremums, infinite sets, etc., can be quite challenging, and take time & effort to learn to do relatively well. It took me a while to think about your problem to determine the solution, as well as how to explain it. The key part of the above is my ($2$). Although I know it's correct, my explanation might not be the most clear and perhaps could use improvement. Please let me know if there's anything you don't understand, as well as any suggestions for how to better explain why ($2$) is true.